# Insert/add paragraph tag <p></p> after some sentences or dot

Tags: php, html

I have some long simple text and i want to insert `<p></p>` tags in it after every 3 sentences. But if there less than 3 sentences, the scipt must do nothing.

For example:

> Without false modesty, we state that we have the best staff possible. And it's not some kind of farce, fiction or someone's evil joke. No, no - this is the most sincere truth. All our employees are incredibly welcoming, smiling, polite, tidy and competent in their work. Thanks to this, our sauna has been working successfully for many years, bringing pleasure to all its customers, both permanent and new. Come, we will be glad to see you.

And I need:

> Without false modesty, we state that we have the best staff possible. And it's not some kind of farce, fiction or someone's evil joke. No, no - this is the most sincere truth. 
>   `<p style='color:red'><a href='link' target='_blank'>Click it!</a></p>`
>   All our employees are incredibly welcoming, smiling, polite, tidy and competent in their work. Thanks to this, our sauna has been working successfully for many years, bringing pleasure to all its customers, both permanent and new. Come, we will be glad to see you.
>   `<p style='color:red'><a href='link' target='_blank'>Click it!</a></p>`

It's just an example. I wrote something like this, but it's not working properly. I don't know what I need to do.

```
 <?php
     $jb=substr_count($personal_text, ".");
     $replacement ="<p></p>";
     if ($jb<=3) {$personal_text333=str_replace("?","?<p></p>",str_replace(".",".<p></p>",str_replace("!","!<p></p>",$personal_text)));
echo $personal_text333; } else {echo $personal_text333;} ?>
```

Comment: Try using the `explode($personal_text, '.')` function. And then work with the array to manage to insert the wanted text.

Comment: @JérémyFerreira thank you. Why you click a minus on my question? And can you give some example?

Comment: Why does this need to be done in PHP? Why not just add the links to the content, if its auto inserted like people are saying then how will you change the link href? XY Problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to capture all to a dot three times.

```
$re = '/(.*?[\.\!\?]){3}/';
// Pattern matches anything to a `.!?` three times. \ is added to make it literal 
$str = 'Without false modesty, we state that we have the best staff possible. And it\'s not some kind of farce, fiction or someone\'s evil joke. No, no - this is the most sincere truth. All our employees are incredibly welcoming, smiling, polite, tidy and competent in their work. Thanks to this, our sauna has been working successfully for many years, bringing pleasure to all its customers, both permanent and new. Come, we will be glad to see you.';
$subst = '$0<p></p>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://regex101.com/r/3myX0x/2

Answer (score -1):

You could split your text into an array like this:

```
$pieces = explode(".", $personal_text);
```

And then glue it back together again:

```
$result = '';
for ($=0; $i<count($pieces); $i++) {
    $result .= $pieces[$i];
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $result .= '<p .../>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Won't this add the tag after every sentence?

Comment: @EnigmaPlus thank you.. Not understand you. Please can you do full example.

Comment: @Andreas after 3 sentences))

Comment: @EnigmaPlus thank you. You are brilliant too. Andreas example work!

Comment: Sorry mate. Still not correct. Here you only add every third sentence. You should add all but every third should have an tag after it. I can edit your code if you want.

Comment: @Andreas.. yeah.. Please.. You can edit. Also sentences can and !|?|.

Comment: That is going to be trickier... I'll wait for enigma to say if I should help him or not

Comment: @Andreas ... sorry)))